# Pycharm freezes upon opening. How do I open Pycharm without opening any projects?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I open Pycharm it tries to open previous projects I was working on. It starts to index these projects and opens the tip of the day. It then freezes - I can't close any windows or do anything within Pycharm.

How do I open Pycharm and not open these projects.

I have tried restarting my machine and re-installing Pycharm.

(running on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 and Pycharm 2017.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by doing are hard uninstall.

Steps taken to do this -

1. Deleting the application
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.2`
3. `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm2017.2`

Then re-install of Pycharm 2017.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old. However, I am new to pycharm and had exactly the same issue. I had ***pycharm-community-2018.1.4*** and this would not start after selection Open-->File or Project. I did a repair installation with ***pycharm-community-182.2949.11***. Boom, it worked like a charm.